# GDB Backtrace with Shared Library Symbols

Tags: c, gdb, net-snmp

I am debugging an application crash using the net-snmp library. The backtrace is as follows:

```
#0  0x001a1c7e in _snmp_parse (sessp=0x0, session=<value optimized out>, pdu=0xb6183858, data=0xa3401248 "\301", length=12097984) at snmp_api.c:4408
#1  0x001a20bb in snmp_resend_request (slp=0x0, rp=0xb6184818, incr_retries=1) at snmp_api.c:6383
#2  0x00b89944 in send_trap_to_sess (sess=0xb6122848, template_pdu=0xa3401440) at agent_trap.c:945
#3  0x00b8ab46 in netsnmp_send_traps (trap=-1, specific=-1, enterprise=0xbbd080, enterprise_length=10, vars=0xa5400468, context=0x0, flags=0)
    at agent_trap.c:839
#4  0x00b8b0fa in send_enterprise_trap_vars (trap=-1, specific=-1, enterprise=0xbbd080, enterprise_length=10, vars=0xa5400468) at agent_trap.c:863
#5  0x00b8b153 in send_trap_vars (trap=-1, specific=-1, vars=0xa5400468) at agent_trap.c:975
#6  0x00b8b1fe in send_v2trap (vars=0xa5400468) at agent_trap.c:1049
#7  0x00288382 in applicationBaseClass::sendTraps (temp=0x161d3018) at appBaseClass.cpp:750
#8  0x00288311 in applicationBaseClass::sendTrapsByTimer (temp=0x161d3018) at appBaseClass.cpp:736
#9  0x00ac05f3 in check_timers () at exec_timer.c:383
```

I installed the net-snmp-debuginfo to get the source files. The details:

```
net-snmp-libs-5.5-57.el6_8.1.i686
net-snmp-utils-5.5-57.el6_8.1.i686
net-snmp-debuginfo-5.5-57.el6_8.1.i686
net-snmp-5.5-57.el6_8.1.i686
```

We can see that the source files correspond to the net-snmp version installed - 5.5-57

Now my application is linking to net-snmp :

```
 [root@stg blr]# lsof -p 4043 | grep snmp
serv_trans  4043 root  mem    REG        8,2  1760620     4031 /usr/lib/libnetsnmpmibs.so.20.0.0
serv_trans  4043 root  mem    REG        8,2   701880     4978 /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.20.0.0
serv_trans  4043 root  mem    REG        8,2   313568     3982 /usr/lib/libnetsnmpagent.so.20.0.0
serv_trans  4043 root  mem    REG        8,2   157008     4017 /usr/lib/libnetsnmphelpers.so.20.0.0
```

So the application is rightly linking with the net-snmp libraries of version 5.5-57

Now, to the backtrace. The stack seems to be incorrect. It is not showing the exact call sequence. For example, in the frame 2, the line number that gdb shows- 6383 -is actually a declaration statement.

```
#1  0x001a20bb in snmp_resend_request (slp=0x0, rp=0xb6184818, incr_retries=1) at snmp_api.c:6383
6383        u_char         *pktbuf = NULL, *packet = NULL;
```

What could be I missing? I seem to be having the right source files for gdb. Why isn't the stack trace from gdb not pointing to the exact sequence of events?

Comment: The pc for frame #2 is shown as agent_trap.c:945, but the source code at that line (I downloaded the debuginfo) shows a call to snmp_async_send, not the snmp_resend_request function shown in frame #1. I checked that snmp_async_send isn't a macro; it's a real function. Something is odd about the pc for frame #1. Maybe the stack got corrupted.

Comment: @Mark, thanks for your comment. Yes. I have the same thought. The function calls shown is incorrect when we check the code.